# My VB.NET Website Hangs For A Long Time Then Displays Nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Okay, this is a weird issue that I've been having with a recent project I'm undertaking.

Occasionally, my website will stop functioning and anytime an ASP page is accessed, the browser will hang for many minutes before bringing up a correctly formatted HTML page with nothing in the  tag. It seems to happen whenever more than one person attempts to access an ASP page, but I'm not positive it's isolated to those conditions.

Let me emphasize that the issue does not arise when accessing directories/HTML pages/other files. Only ASP pages are the problem. I am using lunarpages as a host.

My question is: Does anyone have any prior experience with such an issue, and if so, what are some ways to mitigate it?

Thanks in advance - let me know if I can provide any more pertinent information.

Comment: maybe post some code reduced to still reproduce the problem...

Comment: Here's an updated error, I left the code be overnight without publishing/building. I accessed the site just now and got:

Could not load file or assembly 'BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it may be an issue with your Web Server. Do you have the correct version of .Net installed? Is your Web Server setup to host Asp.Net?

Comment: Yeah, it is set up for hosting .Net web apps. Like I said, it works intermittently.

Comment: So reqests for aspx pages sometimes work and sometimes give that error message? The error message looks like a missing assembly, do you have all the referenced assemblies in the GAC or in the applications bin folder?